# Can i stylize QTreeWidgetItem like QCheckbox?

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

Can i stylize QTreeWidgetItem like QCheckbox?

For my checkboxes style is:

```
 QCheckBox {
     spacing: 15px;
 }

 QCheckBox::indicator {
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
 }

 QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked {
     image: url(:/styles/img/checkbox_unchecked.png);
 }

 QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover {
     image: url(:/styles/img/checkbox_unchecked_hover.png);
 }

 QCheckBox::indicator:checked {
     image: url(:/styles/img/checkbox_checked.png);
 }

 QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover {
     image: url(:/styles/img/checkbox_checked_hover.png);
 }
```

And what style would be for QTreeWidgetItem? I can't find it in documentation :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#qtreeview-widget

Also, http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtreewidgetitem.html
There are quite a few "set" member functions for styling.

Maybe relevant:

[HowTo draw QTreeWidgetItem with different style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179037/howto-draw-qtreewidgetitem-with-different-style)

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26738-QTreeWidget-StyleSheet-problem

Comment: Thanks for reply!

To stylize item in QTreeWidget:

`QTreeWidget::indicator { width: 20px; height: 20px; }
QTreeWidget:indicator:unchecked { background:red;}` etc..